# recursion in implementation of "partition" function

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-recursion, lazy-sequences

I was randomly reading through Clojure source code and I saw that [partition function was defined in terms of recursion without using "recur"](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2853-L2875):

```
(defn partition
  ... ...
  ([n step coll]
     (lazy-seq
       (when-let [s (seq coll)]
         (let [p (doall (take n s))]
           (when (= n (count p))
             (cons p (partition n step (nthrest s step))))))))
  ... ...)
```

Is there any reason of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partition is lazy. The recursive call to `partition` occurs within the body of a `lazy-seq`. Therefore, it is not immediately invoked but returned in a special seq-able object to be evaluated when needed and cache the results realized thus far. The stack depth is limited to one invocation at a time.

A recur without a lazy-seq could be used to create an eager version, but you would not want to use it on sequences of indeterminate length as you can with the version in core.

Comment: This is how I understood your answer: 1. The result might be infinitely long, so we prefer making it lazy here. 2. If it's lazy, using recur or directly calling tail recursion are practically same. I am understanding correctly?

Comment: Definitely not: laziness and tail recursion (using `recur`) are mutually exclusive ways to produce a sequence. If you tried substituting `recur` here for the recursive call, it would fail to compile, as `recur` would not be in the tail position.

Comment: @amalloy Hi amalloy: 1. Are lazy and `recur` mutually exclusive because lazy only evaluate a portion and recur evaluate all at once? 2. I don't understand why it won't compile? Because of syntax of `recur`

Answer (score 4):

To build on @A.Webb's answer and @amalloy's comment:

`recur` is not a shorthand to call the function and it's not a function. It's a special form (what in another language you would call a syntax) to perform tail call optimization.

Tail call optimization is a technique that allows to use recursion without blowing up the stack (without it, every recursive call adds its call frame to the stack). It is not implemented natively in Java (yet), which is why `recur` is used to mark a tail call in Clojure.

Recursion using `lazy-seq` is different because it delays the recursive call by wrapping it in a closure. What it means is that a call to a function implemented in terms of `lazy-seq` (and in particular every recursive call in such a function) returns (immediately) a `LazySeq` sequence, whose computation is delayed until it is iterated through.

---

To illustrate and qualify @amalloy's comment that `recur` and laziness are mutually exclusive, here's an implementation of `filter` that uses both techniques:

```
(defn filter [pred coll]
  (letfn [(step [pred coll]
            (when-let [[x & more] (seq coll)]
              (if (pred x)
                (cons x (lazy-seq (step pred more))) ;; lazy recursive call
                (recur pred more))))]                ;; tail call
    (lazy-seq (step pred coll))))

(filter even? (range 10))
;; => (0 2 4 6 8)
```

Both techniques can be used in the same function, but not for the same recursive call ; the function wouldn't compile if the lazy recursive call to `step` used `recur` because in this case `recur` wouldn't be in tail call position (the result of the tail call would not be returned directly but would be passed to `lazy-seq`).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what I am confused! I really wish SO allows me to accept multiple answers!

Answer (score 2):

All of the lazy functions are written this way. This implementation of `partition` would blow the stack without the call to `lazy-seq` for a large enough sequence.

Read a bit about TCO (tail call optimization) if you are more interested in how `recur` works. When you are using tail recursion it means you can jump out of your current function call without losing anything. In the case of this implementation you wouldn't be able to do that because you are `cons`-ing `p` on the next call of `partition`. Being in tail position means you are the last thing being called. In the implementation `cons` is in tail position. `recur` only works on tail position to guarantee TCO.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what I am confused! I really wish SO allows me to accept multiple answers!